# Mocking Linked Dummy Data

Tags: c#, linq, mocking

I am using a database with one to many links using foreign keys.

I trying mocking data for example (vastly simplified)

```
List<Account> account = new List<Account> {
    new Account { id = 1, name = "ABC" }
};

List<Transaction> trans = new List<Transaction {     
    new Transaction { AccountID = 1, Quant = 1 },
    new Transaction { AccountID = 1, Quant = 3 }
};
```

How do I mock it so that in my query I can use the linq query such as

```
var a = unitofwork.Accounts.FirstorDefault().Transaction;
```

This works when I build in Context from database and use modelbuilder to tell the links but how can I get this to work outside in a mocking framework?

Comment: What you're trying to unit test? You need to give more information, for example, what entities do you have in your data access layer (classes that make calls to `entity framework`)?

Comment: That's why we separate data and business in code. If you had used some kind of data abstraction layer like Repository pattern you would have not had that problem.

Comment: Side note: it makes no sense to do `FirstOrDefault().Transaction` because if it can't be found then a null reference exception will be thrown. It would be better to do `First().Transaction` if there absolutely has to be one there or do some null checks.

Comment: I can't help but feel deja vu here. This question has got have been asked a million times already!